# JavaFX - The FileChooser window is opening but the default initialModality isn't working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I created an application, in which i have to click on a MenuItem "Open..." to open a FileChooser. The FileChooser do open, but the problem is that i can click or close the first window while this FileChooser is is still opened.

Do i have a problem in my code ? Is it wrong to put `primaryStage` as a parameter to `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);` ?

These are my declarations

```
private Stage primaryStage;
```

This is my start method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("Ontology - Language Disorders");
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    initRootLayout();
    showOntologyOverview();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This is my OpenDialog

```
@FXML
private void handleOpenMenuItem(ActionEvent event){
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("OWL (*.owl)", "*.owl"));
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
}
```

My initRootLayout :

```
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what's happening ._. i really don't know why,i still can do any interaction like close the main window :(

Comment: I'm confused. Is this your `Application` subclass, or is it your controller class?

Comment: i used the same class for both, i means the main app has these methods.

Comment: Same class, but you have different instances of that class. Where do you initialize `primaryStage` in the controller instance? (That is generally a terrible idea, by the way; it's way too confusing as it's almost impossible to keep track of which things have been initialized and which methods have been called.)

Comment: I am confused with the question and therefore deleted my comment. Do you have `multiple stages` while you are opening a `FileChooser`?

Comment: james_D i added the initRootLayout

Comment: Please add all the code as edits to the question.

Comment: ItachiUchiha, yeah i have a menuItem "Open.." like every application and i just want to open that filechooser (as i said opening but not perfectly working)

Comment: Methods Code Added !

Comment: There is no need to call `primaryStage.show()` inside `start()` and `initRootLayout()`. Just call it from one place. The code doesn't make any sense as to why your code is not working as intended. Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `Application` class as the controller class for your FXML. This is highly confusing and you should avoid it.

Here is what happens:

1. You launch the application. This causes the FX toolkit to be initialized, the FX Application Thread to start, an instance of your `Application` subclass to be created, a `Stage` to be created and `start(...)` to be invoked on that instance, on the FX Application Thread.
2. Your `start` method sets the `primaryStage` field of the instance created by the startup sequence
3. You create an `FXMLLoader` and load the FXML file.
4. The `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of the controller class (which happens to be the `Application` subclass). It then initializes all `@FXML`-annotated fields on that instance, and registers handler methods. Note that the `primaryStage` field is never initialized on this instance.

When the user presses the "Open" `MenuItem`, the `handleOpenMenuItem()` method is invoked on the instance created in step 4 (not the instance created in step 1). You create the `FileChooser`, and call `showOpenDialog(...)` passing in the value of `primaryStage`. Since `primaryStage` is `null` in this instance, the file chooser has no owner window, and so cannot implement any meaningful modality.

To fix this, create a separate class for your controller. You can get the window by calling `getScene().getWindow()` on any node in the scene.

Comment: YEAAAAAAAY! the problem was in the intialization :D thanks both of you ! :D